ubuntu driverfor an ADDON PCI WiFi card
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 on my PC which is fitted with an ADDON NWP 201E wireless PCI card. I need a ubuntu driver for it but ADDON`s telephone number does not respond and messages are not answered. I do not know if the company has ceased trading or if there is some other problem but if anyone can please tell me where I can get the driver, I would be very grateful.
